# What does “eaten apple” indicate?

Tags: meaning

[image]

Doesn’t “eaten apple” indicate food in the stomach to be digested or already digested?

Why did “eaten apple” lead me to this picture?

Can “eaten apple” indicate both left food and swallowed food on the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are discussing this apple in a very (very) specific context, an "eaten apple" indicates an **apple that has been eaten**, not the food in a stomach.  The apple in your picture has been eaten and is thus an "eaten apple".

I suppose it is possible that someone could be talking about digesting food when using "eaten apple" but it really is rare and depends fully on the context.  And though it might work, it would probably not be necessary to use "apple eaten" exactly; a range of similar phrases could work.  For example,

> The [apple / eaten apple / apple eaten / apple you have eaten] has been disrupting your digestive process.

Comment: Is it a difference between definition 1a and 2? https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=eat&submit.x=0&submit.y=0

Comment: @user09827 Definition 2 is a metaphorical usage, like "My time was *eaten up* by answering telephone calls all day."  You

Answer (score 1):

As the saying goes, you can't have your cake and eat it too. Once you have eaten your apple, it's gone. So you can't say that it's an eaten apple.

Per Mr Bunting's comments, it's an apple core - though the eater has left a lot of good stuff uneaten. You can also  say that it's a half-eaten apple or a leftover apple.

Comment: It's an 'apple core' - though  the eater has left a lot of good stuff uneaten!